# How to remove the wording "metric" in apache superset "pivot tables v2"?

Tags: pivot-table, apache-superset

Inside the apache superset pivot v2 tables, the word "metric" appears between the columns (as in the image). I don't like it and my intention is to remove it.  What can I do to remove or hide it?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
.pivot_table_v_2 table.pvtTable thead tr:nth-child(1) th.pvtAxisLabel
{
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Actually Pauls answer was almost right, you need to change nth-of-type, just change this part instead of nth-child. If you change nth-of-type 1,2,3.. you can change the colors of text, aswell as background and all other parameters. I was looking for exactly the same thing and it works on 2.1

```
.pivot_table_v_2 table.pvtTable thead tr:nth-of-type(2) th.pvtAxisLabel
{
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: In my situation, it worked exactly Paul's answer, and your code made the text white in a cell below the necessary cell. (v2.0.0)

Comment: Yes with tr:nth-of-type(2), with tr:nth-of-type(1) you change the first row, with 3 the third and so on